# C#: как получить среднюю яркость изображения

Tags: c#

Использую `System.Drawing` и `ImageMagick`. Получить яркость попиксельно - не вариант, `Bitmap.getPixel()` слишком медленно работает. Вероятно, мне следует получить RGB-каналы? Есть ли какие-нибудь способы это сделать быстро?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Яркость определяется как `Max(R, G, B)`.

А может просто не проверять ВСЕ пиксели, а лишь каждый 4/8/16. По сути значение будет вполне верны, но чем больше шаг, тем больше погрешность от реального значения. Ссумируйте значение каналов по трём переменным и поделите на число подсчитанных пикселей.

Реализовав протестируйте на одной и той-же картинке разный шаг, увидите разницу и выберите приемлимую точность.